# Use other method to play sound simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, methods, avaudioplayer, argument-passing

I'm trying to play 2 different sounds simultaniously, which works perfectly when putting all code in 2 separate methods. Instead I thought creating a method which contains the soundplayer code and call that method from another with the song name as an argument. This a works ... almost.

Press button 1 -> sound one plays. Good!!!
Press button 2 -> sound1 stops and sound2 starts. Not Good!!!

How to make sound two to keep his/her fingers away from sound one.

Here's the code. It's probably a simple one, but I'm stuck for a while now.

```
.
.
.
-(IBAction) playSound1
{
    NSString *nameOfSong = @"song1";
   [self nowPlay:nameOfSong];
}

-(IBAction) playSound2
{
    NSString *nameOfSong = @"song2";
    [self nowPlay:nameOfSong];
}

-(void) nowReallyPlay:(NSString*) whatsTheName
{ 
    NSURL *playSong = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:whatsTheName ofType:@"mp3"]];  
    self.soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playSong error:nil];
    soundPlayer.delegate = self;
    soundPlayer.volume= 0.5;
    soundPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [soundPlayer play];
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining 2 different AudioPlayers and select which one to play using if statements.

It works but still is not very sexy in my honest opinion. For my program (App for my little girl) it will do just fine, but what if one would want 25 sound playing at ones? Would you have to create 25 AVPlayers?

Is there another (sexier) way to take this hurdle ?

```
.
.
-(IBAction) playSound1
{
NSString *nameOfSong = @"song1";
NSString *playThis = @"first_song";
[self nowPlay:nameOfSong:playThis];
}

-(IBAction) playSound2
{
NSString *nameOfSong = @"song2";
NSString *playThis = @"second_song";
[self nowPlay:nameOfSong:playThis];
}

-(void) nowReallyPlay:(NSString*) whatsTheName : (NSString*) playWhat
{ 
if (playWhat == @"first_song")
{
    NSURL *playSong = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:whatsTheName ofType:@"mp3"]];  
    self.soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playSong error:nil];
    sound1Player.delegate = self;
    sound1Player.volume= 0.5;
    sound1Player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [sound1Player play];

} else if (playWhat == @"second_song"") {

    NSURL *playSong = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:whatsTheName ofType:@"mp3"]];  
    self.sound2Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:playSong error:nil];

    sound2Player.delegate = self;
    sound2Player.volume= 0.5;
    sound2Player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [sound2Player play];
    }
}
.
.
```

Comment: Not THE response frequency in was honing for. Somebody outthere must be triggered to reply something...or at least call me à donkey.